# Url Mapping fails for /oauth/token - Spring security + OAuth in a Grails application

Tags: grails, spring-security, oauth-2.0, url-mapping

I am building a grails application that includes:

1. Spring Security (Spring MVC project; NOT the Grails plugin)
2. "OAuth for Spring Security" to implement an OAuth2 provider

To accomplish this, I followed the following steps:

- grails install-templates  [[see here]](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Command%20Line/install-templates.html)
- in src/templates/war/web.xml, add the Spring Security filter as below:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

- define Spring Security and OAuth beans in WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml file including the following for handling /oauth/token

```
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
 xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request parameters -->     
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>
....
....
<oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
    <oauth:authorization-code />
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <oauth:password />
</oauth:authorization-server>
```

**Issue:** The issue that I am facing is that Spring Security filters fire correctly and successfully authenticate the client. **But after that, the GrailsDispatcherServlet is unable to find a handler for the POST to /oauth/token and returns a "404 Resource not found" error.**

In the debug log, I can see that /oauth/token is mapped to a handler

```
2013-06-17 19:21:04,469 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  endpoint.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping  - Mapped "{[/oauth/token],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.getAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.lang.String,java.util.Map)
```

I suspect, this happens because when GrailsDispatcherServlet and ApplicationContext is created, the Grails' DefaultUrlMappingsHolder creates a new set of URL mappings in that context and replaces the previous set of mappings. For e.g., I also see the following in my debug log

```
2013-06-17 19:31:01,339 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Reverse mapping: [DefaultUrlMappingsHolder.UrlMappingKey@250f9a46 controller = 'account', action = [null], plugin = [null], params = set['API_VERSION']] -> /()/provisioning/order/account/()?
```

Here's the debug log for when I make an HTTP post to //oauth/token

```
2013-06-17 19:31:05,798 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG util.AntPathRequestMatcher  - Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token'
2013-06-17 19:31:05,804 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /oauth/token at position 1 of 5 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2013-06-17 19:31:05,805 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /oauth/token at position 2 of 5 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2013-06-17 19:31:05,807 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  - Basic Authentication Authorization header found for user 'j2'
2013-06-17 19:31:05,808 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG authentication.ProviderManager  - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
2013-06-17 19:31:05,813 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  - Authentication success: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@ffff9a33: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@d08: Username: j2; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ALL; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ALL
2013-06-17 19:31:05,813 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /oauth/token at position 3 of 5 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2013-06-17 19:31:05,814 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /oauth/token at position 4 of 5 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2013-06-17 19:31:05,814 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /oauth/token at position 5 of 5 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2013-06-17 19:31:05,814 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG util.AntPathRequestMatcher  - Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token'
2013-06-17 19:31:05,815 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /oauth/token; Attributes: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY]
2013-06-17 19:31:05,815 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@ffff9a33: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@d08: Username: j2; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ALL; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ALL
2013-06-17 19:31:05,815 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG vote.AffirmativeBased  - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@35f3198f, returned: 0
2013-06-17 19:31:05,815 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG vote.AffirmativeBased  - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@6b1316f4, returned: 1
2013-06-17 19:31:05,815 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Authorization successful
2013-06-17 19:31:05,816 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2013-06-17 19:31:05,816 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /oauth/token reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2013-06-17 19:31:05,826 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter  - Bound Grails request context to thread: SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@519cea9e]]
2013-06-17 19:31:05,846 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG filter.UrlMappingsFilter  - Executing URL mapping filter...
2013-06-17 19:31:05,847 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG filter.UrlMappingsFilter  - URL Mappings
------------
/
/(*)/provisioning/order/account/(*)?
/(*)/provisioning/order/demographics/(*)?
/(*)/provisioning/inventory/phone_numbers/(*)?
/(*)/billing/regions/(*)?
/(*)/billing/countries/(*)?
/(*)/provisioning/credit_cards/(*)?
/(*)/provisioning/states/(*)?
/(*)/provisioning/countries/(*)?
/(*)/provisioning/phone_cities/(*)?
/(*)/general/languages/(*)?
/(*)/docs/constraints/(*)?

2013-06-17 19:31:05,847 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/oauth/token] with pattern [/]
2013-06-17 19:31:05,847 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/oauth/token] with pattern [/(*)/provisioning/order/account/(*)?]
2013-06-17 19:31:05,847 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/oauth/token] with pattern [/(*)/provisioning/order/demographics/(*)?]
2013-06-17 19:31:05,848 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/oauth/token] with pattern [/(*)/provisioning/inventory/phone_numbers/(*)?]
2013-06-17 19:31:05,848 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/oauth/token] with pattern [/(*)/billing/regions/(*)?]
2013-06-17 19:31:05,848 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/oauth/token] with pattern [/(*)/billing/countries/(*)?]
2013-06-17 19:31:05,848 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/oauth/token] with pattern [/(*)/provisioning/credit_cards/(*)?]
2013-06-17 19:31:05,848 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/oauth/token] with pattern [/(*)/provisioning/states/(*)?]
2013-06-17 19:31:05,848 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/oauth/token] with pattern [/(*)/provisioning/countries/(*)?]
2013-06-17 19:31:05,848 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/oauth/token] with pattern [/(*)/provisioning/phone_cities/(*)?]
2013-06-17 19:31:05,848 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/oauth/token] with pattern [/(*)/general/languages/(*)?]
2013-06-17 19:31:05,848 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/oauth/token] with pattern [/(*)/docs/constraints/(*)?]
2013-06-17 19:31:05,857 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG filter.UrlMappingsFilter  - No match found, processing remaining filter chain.
2013-06-17 19:31:05,860 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter  - Cleared Grails thread-bound request context: SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@519cea9e]]
2013-06-17 19:31:05,860 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG access.ExceptionTranslationFilter  - Chain processed normally
2013-06-17 19:31:05,860 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter  - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Any ideas on how to "share"/"propagate" those Spring /oauth/token mappings with the Grails Dispatcher?

Comment: This is kind of irregular, because what you're doing is standing up two different application contexts and then trying to share only portions of one context with another. Could you instead include the necessary dependencies in the Grails project and then add the spring oauth applicationContext config to grails-app/conf/resources.xml?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Daniel. When I moved all Spring & OAuth configuration into grails-app/conf/resources.xml, the result is still the same. The filters fire as expected, client is authenticated but Grails can't find a handler for /oauth/token. The debug log is exactly as posted in the question above.

Comment: Also, check out this documentation for OAuth2 [TokenEndpoint](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/TokenEndpoint.html)  
/oauth/token is mapped to that class using  
@RequestMapping(value="/oauth/token")  
From the debug log, it looks like this mapping is detected during initialization, but somehow Grails doesn't know about it.

Comment: It's because grails doesn't know about your filter. You might be able to programmatically register it: https://gist.github.com/danveloper/bc94f74e2d151825c584

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into similar symptoms when trying to get my /oauth/authorize endpoint to work properly.  In order to get things going, I had to add the following to UrlMappings.groovy:

```
    "/oauth/authorize" (uri:"/oauth/authorize.dispatch")
    "/oauth/token" (uri:"/oauth/token.dispatch")
```

This solution came from examining the source for a grails spring-security-oauth provider plugin:

https://github.com/adaptivecomputing/grails-spring-security-oauth2-provider

Note that getting this setup to work completely *might* also involve updating the grails cache plugin: when using 1.0.1, I received a 500 after I got the mapping to work (when trying to load /oauth/authorize).  Upgrading my cache plugin to 1.1.1 fixed that issue for me.

Hope something in there is useful.